# Stack underflow on multiple string concatenations using Gforth

Tags: string, algorithm, forth, gforth, stackunderflow

From [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_concatenation#Forth), I'm using the following as a way to concatenate strings in Forth.

```
s" hello" pad place
pad count type
s"  there!" pad +place
pad count type
```

Using this code, I'd like to be able to concatenate multiple strings together. However, the following fails on Gforth

```
s" hi " pad place 
s" hello " pad place
s" world" pad 
+place
pad +place
pad count type
```

From my basic Forth exposure, I see the code as putting three strings on the stack, then appending the string on the top of the stack with the string below it, then appending the new string on the stack again with the bottom one.

Why does this code underflows on the last +place? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Unrelated to my answer, `place` doesn't seem to be documented in the Gforth manual but definitely is defined which seems a little odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second snippet copies "hi " to the memory location `pad`, then copies the "hello " to the same location (overwriting "hi ").

So when you try the first `+place` it takes the `addr u` reference for "world " from the stack and then appends "world " to "hello ". So if you try

```
s" hi " pad place 
s" hello " pad place
s" world" pad +place

//Display the string at pad
pad count type
```

You should see `hello world ok`

At this point all of your `place` or `+place` words have used up all of the string references on  the stack. To check this if you just run

```
s" hi " pad place 
s" hello " pad place
s" world" pad 
+place

//Check the stack
.s
```

You will see an empty stack.

Now when you use `pad` again it pushes the address that `pad` represents to the stack. So the next `+place` doesn't have a string reference on the stack for it to copy, and so it fails.

To fix this you want something like this instead

```
s" hi " pad place 
s" hello " pad +place
s" world" pad +place
pad count type
```

In this code the "hello " does not overwrite the "hi " and is instead appended to it, so the next `+place` has the right arguments on  the stack and works as expected.